# How do I prevent canvas drag from affecting item movability in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drag-and-drop, tkinter-canvas

Python canvas drag affects item drag

Dragging the canvas in a specific direction is affecting the dragability of the items. For example, let's assume there are images labeled A1, B1, and C1 on the canvas. When you move the canvas, the item on the opposite side of the drag direction (C1 in this case) is the only one that moves. Attempting to move A1 or B1 doesn't result in any movement, but C1 moves instead. Alternatively, if the image on the opposite side is A1, when you try to move B1 or C1, they don't move, and instead, A1 moves. The issue here is that dragging the canvas is unintentionally affecting the movement of the items and their ability to be moved.

To address this problem, the canvas should be draggable without affecting the items or their movability. After dragging the canvas in a direction, the item you intend to move should be the one that actually moves, regardless of its position on the canvas. The current behavior only allows the item on the opposite side of the drag direction to move, which is causing the issue.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x600")

canvas = Canvas(win, width=1000, height=1000, bg="white")
x_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(win, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
x_scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(win, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
y_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

drag_data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'item': None}

# Function to start dragging an image
def start_drag(event):
    drag_data['item'] = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    drag_data['x'] = event.x
    drag_data['y'] = event.y

# Function to stop dragging an image
def stop_drag(event):
    drag_data['item'] = None
    drag_data['x'] = 0
    drag_data['y'] = 0

# Function to move the dragged image
def drag(event):
    if drag_data['item']:
        delta_x = event.x - drag_data['x']
        delta_y = event.y - drag_data['y']
        canvas.move(drag_data['item'], delta_x, delta_y)
        drag_data['x'] = event.x
        drag_data['y'] = event.y

image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('a1.png'))
img1 = canvas.create_image(147, 130, anchor=NW, image=image1)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('b1.png'))
img2 = canvas.create_image(400, 300, anchor=NW, image=image2)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c1.png'))
img3 = canvas.create_image(700, 500, anchor=NW, image=image3)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

# Variables to track canvas position
canvas_offset_x = 0
canvas_offset_y = 0
dragged_item = None

def get_canvas_coordinates(event):
    global dragged_item
    
    canvas_x = canvas.canvasx(event.x) - canvas_offset_x
    canvas_y = canvas.canvasy(event.y) - canvas_offset_y
    print("Canvas coordinates: x={}, y={}".format(canvas_x, canvas_y))
    
    # Check if an item is being dragged
    if dragged_item is not None:
        item_x1, item_y1, item_x2, item_y2 = canvas.coords(dragged_item)
        item_width = item_x2 - item_x1
        item_height = item_y2 - item_y1
        item_x = canvas_x - item_width/2
        item_y = canvas_y - item_height/2
        canvas.coords(dragged_item, item_x, item_y, item_x + item_width, item_y + item_height)
    
    adjust_item_coordinates()

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", get_canvas_coordinates)

def limit_canvas_scroll(canvas, x, y):
    canvas.scan_dragto(x, y, gain=1)

def adjust_item_coordinates():
    # Get the visible area of the canvas
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox("all")

    # Update the canvas offset
    global canvas_offset_x, canvas_offset_y
    canvas_offset_x = x1
    canvas_offset_y = y1

    # Adjust the coordinates of each item
    for item in canvas.find_all():
        if item != dragged_item:
            # Get the current item coordinates
            item_x1, item_y1, item_x2, item_y2 = canvas.coords(item)
            
            # Calculate the item center point
            item_center_x = (item_x1 + item_x2) / 2
            item_center_y = (item_y1 + item_y2) / 2
            
            # Calculate the distance from item center to the dragged canvas position
            distance_x = item_center_x - canvas_offset_x
            distance_y = item_center_y - canvas_offset_y
            
            # Update the item coordinates based on the distance
            canvas.move(item, -distance_x, -distance_y)

# Bind the canvas scrolling to mouse events
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", lambda event: canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y))
canvas.bind("<B2-Motion>", lambda event: limit_canvas_scroll(canvas, event.x, event.y))
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-2>", lambda event: adjust_item_coordinates())

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `get_canvas_coordinates()`.

Comment: get_canvas_coordinates() I needed to see relative coordinates to see if items protects their coordinates. That function gives me accurate coordinates after dragging canvas and items.

Comment: Comment out line 80. Worked for me. No issue.

Comment: The scrollbar doesn't do anything.

Comment: problem is not with that after dragging canvas try dragging each item you will see what the problem is

Comment: This is a sample code that has same problem as original The scrollbar is part of full code. My problem is after dragging the canvas, draggability of items gets affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you handle the dragging properly, `adjust_item_coordinates()` and `get_canvas_coordinates()` are not required:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x600")

canvas = Canvas(win, width=1000, height=1000, bg="white")
x_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(win, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
x_scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(win, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
y_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

drag_data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'item': None}

# Function to start dragging an image
def start_drag(event):
    #drag_data['item'] = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    drag_data['item'] = canvas.find_withtag("current")[0]  # get item under mouse cursor
    drag_data['x'] = event.x
    drag_data['y'] = event.y

# Function to stop dragging an image
def stop_drag(event):
    drag_data['item'] = None
    drag_data['x'] = 0
    drag_data['y'] = 0
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")) # update scrollregion

# Function to move the dragged image
def drag(event):
    if drag_data['item']:
        delta_x = event.x - drag_data['x']
        delta_y = event.y - drag_data['y']
        canvas.move(drag_data['item'], delta_x, delta_y)
        drag_data['x'] = event.x
        drag_data['y'] = event.y

image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('a1.png'))
img1 = canvas.create_image(147, 130, anchor=NW, image=image1)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img1, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('b1.png'))
img2 = canvas.create_image(400, 300, anchor=NW, image=image2)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img2, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c1.png'))
img3 = canvas.create_image(700, 500, anchor=NW, image=image3)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<ButtonPress-1>', start_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_drag)
canvas.tag_bind(img3, '<B1-Motion>', drag)

# Bind the canvas scrolling to mouse events
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", lambda event: canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y))
canvas.bind("<B2-Motion>", lambda event: canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1))

win.mainloop()
```